# Quadratic Casimir of symplectic group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Does anyone know the formula for the value of quadratic Casimir of the symplectic group $Sp(2N)$ in the fundamental representation? In this definition, $Sp(2)=SU(2)$. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  What kind of formula are you looking for?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra#Casimir_operators

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I meant a formula for the value of the quadratic Casimir for any $N$ in, say, the fundamental representation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that I understand your question, so I will first state the question that I am going to answer. 
Let $G$ be a compact connected semisimple Lie group and let $\Omega$ be the associated Casimir element, which lies in the universal enveloping algebra of the complexified Lie algebra $\mathfrak g_{\mathbb C}$ of $G$. 
For $\pi:G\to GL(V_\pi)$ an irreducible representation, the linear transformation $d\pi(\Omega):V_\pi\to V_\pi$ commutes with $\pi(g)$ for every $g$, thus by Schur's Lemma $d\pi(\Omega)$ is a scalar multiple of the identity transformation on $V_\pi$, i.e. $d\pi(\Omega)= \lambda_\pi \mathrm{Id}_{V_\pi}$.

I suppose that you are asking the value of $\lambda_\pi$ for $G=\mathrm{Sp}(n)$ and $\pi$ its **standard** representation.
In general, 
$$
\lambda_\pi = \langle \Lambda_\pi+2\delta,\Lambda_\pi \rangle,
$$
where $\Lambda_\pi$ is the highest weight of $\pi$, $\delta$ is the half sum of the positive roots, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is minus de Killing form. 
See Prop. 5.28 in Knapp's book "Lie groups beyond an introduction".

In your case, under the standard notation used in Knapp's book, the highest weight of the standard representation is $\Lambda_\pi=\varepsilon_1$ and furthermore, $\delta = \sum_{j=1}^n (n+1-j)\varepsilon_j$. 
Hence, $\lambda_\pi$ is a positive multiple of $n+1$.